# insert value in a table from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Plase someone help me in adding a value from table to another table in `sql server`

I have one table with columns `(reserve,name,price)`

and another table with columns `(name,price)`

i want to insert into `table1(price)` value from `table2(price)`

Comment: check this: http://sqlandme.com/2013/06/18/sql-server-update-table-with-inner-join/

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(Price) 
(
    SELECT Price FROM TABLE2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

posting as answer:

If you are trying to update price column in Table1 to values in Table2(Price):

```
UPDATE TBL1
SET    TBL1.Price = TBL2.Price
FROM   Table1 TBL1
INNER JOIN Table2 TBL2 ON TBL1.name = TBL2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{ 
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2(name,price) SELECT name,price from table1", con);
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query:** Inserting data from one table to another

**1) Using Insert into :**  It is used when table is already created in the database earlier and data is to be inserted into this table from another table also having ***same schemas***

```
 insert into tb1 (name,price) select name,price from tb2;
```

**2) Using Select into:**  It is used only if the table specified in the INTO clause does not exist. It will create  new table same data types as selected columns.

```
select name,price into tb3 from tb2;
```

**[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9e5b/3)**

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table1(price) select price from table2
```